# Closing multiple Dialogs at once

Tags: android, dialog

Im writing an Android application in which a user selection triggers a custom `Dialog`, from which a selection may trigger a second `Dialog`.

When showing the initial `Dialog` from the Activity class, I'm setting an `onDismissListener` on it to pull out user selections which works fine other in cases where the 2nd Dialog is not triggered. The issue that I'm having is that I can't figure out how to have the first one Dialog remain open until the 2nd one is dismissed, so that the information from both is sent back to the Activity class.

Hopefully some code will make this a little more clear:

MainActivity class where I am launching the initial CustomDialog:

```
customDialog = new CustomDialog(this);
                customDialog.show();
                customDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface di){
                        slection = customDialog.getselection();
                        updateUI(); //updates a listview with the results
                    }
                });
```

Within the CustumDialog class where I am launching the SecondDialog on top of it:

```
if(specify){
    SecondDialog secondDialog = new SecondDialog(context);
    secondDialog.show();
    secondDialog.setOnDismissListener( new OnDissmissListener(){
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface di){
            // this is where I want to call the CustomDialog's dismiss() method
            // so that they both close at the same time and the data from here
            // can be sent back to the MainActiivty through the CustomDialog's
            // onDismissListener

        }
    });
}
dismiss();
```

So, to reiterate: I'm trying to prevent the CustomDialog's `dismiss()` method to be called until the SecondDialog is also dismissed. Is there a way that I can call it from the SecondDialog's OnDismissListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `customDialog` as an instance level variable. You then it will be accessible with `onDismiss(...)` of second dialog. There you can call `customDialog.dismiss();`

```
// Instance level variable
private Dialog customDialog = null;
```

Instanciate your `customDialog`, then create second dialog from within your customDialog. Your Second dialog's code would look like this.

```
if(specify){
    SecondDialog secondDialog = new SecondDialog(context);
    secondDialog.show();
    secondDialog.setOnDismissListener( new OnDissmissListener(){
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface di){
            // customDialog is accessible as it is declared as instance level variable
            MyClassName.this.customDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
}
dismiss();
```

Comment: Thanks, is is basically what I was looking for. I forgot I could just make it static in the MainActivity and reference as such in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to save the data in 1st dialog before going to send one and when dismiss the 2nd dialog, open the 1st dialog again with saved data .. i used this way in my developing and its effective ..